# Which Maqam is Haftarah Chanted In?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, music, trop-cantillation

In the Sephardic/Edot Ha Mizrach tradition, [the te'amim of the Torah are chanted in maqam sigah/sikah](http://pizmonim.org/maqam.php?maqam=Sigah). Which maqam is the Haftarah chanted in?

Note:

> A maqam (مقام), which in Arabic literally means 'place', is a standard
>   melody type and set of related tunes. The musical traditions of
>   Mizrahi Jews  are  based on the maqam system. Ashkenazi nusach
>   includes a simplified system including three main modes or steyger and
>   several minor variants. Muslims share the same practice of conducting
>   services using the maqam, but differ substantially in many ways.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Maqam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Egyptians chant Haftarah in Maqam Bayyat or Hoseini.

According to Rabbi Mordechai Cohen, the Yerushalmi Haftarah is in maqam Garga.